# SSRS 2008 R2 - empty reports (no data)

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

When using Reporting Services SSRS 2008 R2 to generate reports in several formats, some reports are empty (no data found) based on the conditions/parameters used.

Is there a way to detect an empty dataset when using Reporting Web Services? The report is executed on the server so the client has no way of detecting that there is no data.
Is there a way around this?

Jawahar

Comment: so if the report is empty - you want to show a standard message like 'No Records found'...is this what u wanna do?

Comment: That's correct, I want to display a message on the web page or even an alert to say "no data found"

Answer (score 0):

You can check those things right away in the report builder by running the query. It will be same way in SSRS 2008. Try to click on dataset ...go to query and click on "!" button that would show the results if there are any